# How to add an image to the footer in fpdf in php

Tags: image, fpdf

I tried to add image in footer of `html2fpdf` class.

```
function Footer() {
        //This is the footer; it's repeated on each page.
        //enter filename: phpjabber logo, x position: (page width/2)-half the picture size,
        //y position: rough estimate, width, height, filetype, link: click it!
        $this->Image("uploads/footer.jpg", (8.5/2)-1.5, 9.8, 3, 1, "JPG", "http://www.abc.com");
    }
```

Please help , how to add image in footer in `fpdf`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

use $this->GetY() for set height in function Image

```
$pdf->Image($image1, 5, $pdf->GetY(), 33.78);
```

or even

```
$pdf->Image($image1, 5, null, 33.78);
```